# Converting part of a ByteBuffer to a String

Tags: java, string, nio, bytebuffer

I have a ByteBuffer containing bytes that were derived by [`String.getBytes(charsetName)`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28java.lang.String%29), where "containing" means that the string comprises the entire sequence of bytes between the ByteBuffer's `position()` and `limit()`.

What's the best way for me to get the string back? (assuming I know the encoding charset) Is there anything better than the following (which seems a little clunky)

```
byte[] ba = new byte[bbuf.remaining()];
bbuf.get(ba);
try {
    String s = new String(ba, charsetName);
}
catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    /* take appropriate action */
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
String s = Charset.forName(charsetName).decode(bbuf).toString();
```

Comment: whee! Great -- it "smelled" like there should be something to do this